# nav-pills not working in my code (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add nav-pills to  tag but it's not working, why?
I really tried everything but nothing works!

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Add New Post</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pills require the `active` class.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Add New Post</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/xrln5uphko